# Normalizing unicode text to filenames, etc. in Python

Tags: python, unicode, plone, normalization, unicode-normalization

Are there any standalonenish solutions for normalizing international unicode text to safe ids and filenames in Python?

E.g. turn `My International Text: åäö` to `my-international-text-aao`

[plone.i18n](https://github.com/plone/plone.i18n) does really good job, but unfortunately it depends on `zope.security` and `zope.publisher` and some other packages making it fragile dependency.

[Some operations that plone.i18n applies](https://github.com/plone/plone.i18n/blob/master/plone/i18n/normalizer/__init__.py)

Comment: "My International Text: åäö" is a perfectly valid filename on all of the systems I use, so you might want to be a bit more specific. For example, exactly what characters do you want to (dis)allow?

Comment: @LaurenceGonsalves It might be perfectly valid, but that doesn't mean it will necessarily survive a particular web server / web browser / web OS combo when downloading. When that bug report arrives it's usually faster to just strip the accents than try to figure out where the problem lies.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to remove accents in a python unicode string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/517923/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-accents-in-a-python-unicode-string)

Comment: Looke at how [`unidecode`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode)`(`[`slugify`](https://github.com/mozilla/unicode-slugify/blob/master/slugify/__init__.py)`(u'My International Text: åäö'))` are implemented [ignore django dependence it is not necessary for Unicode input].

Answer (score 35, accepted):

What you want to do is also known as "slugify" a string. Here's a possible solution:

```
import re
from unicodedata import normalize

_punct_re = re.compile(r'[\t !"#$%&\'()*\-/<=>?@\[\\\]^_`{|},.:]+')

def slugify(text, delim=u'-'):
    """Generates an slightly worse ASCII-only slug."""
    result = []
    for word in _punct_re.split(text.lower()):
        word = normalize('NFKD', word).encode('ascii', 'ignore')
        if word:
            result.append(word)
    return unicode(delim.join(result))
```

Usage:

```
>>> slugify(u'My International Text: åäö')
u'my-international-text-aao'
```

You can also change the delimeter:

```
>>> slugify(u'My International Text: åäö', delim='_')
u'my_international_text_aao'
```

**Source:** [Generating Slugs](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/5/)

**For Python 3:** [pastebin.com/ft7Yb3KS](http://pastebin.com/ft7Yb3KS) (thanks [@MrPoxipol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2221315/mrpoxipol)).

Comment: can somebody tell me why did I get downvoted? (man, I hate those "anonymous downvoters")

Comment: Many names for the same procedure :) Thank you for a very good answer.

Comment: I, too, hate down-voting without commenting to explain why you down-voted. Please always explain your down-votes.

Comment: this solution (like others) doesn't handle characters that cannot be decomposed by Unicode normalization, like ß or œ.

Answer (score 4):

The way to solve this problem is to make a decision on which characters are allowed (different systems have different rules for valid identifiers.

Once you decide on which characters are allowed, write an *allowed()* predicate and a dict subclass for use with [*str.translate*](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate):

```
def makesafe(text, allowed, substitute=None):
    ''' Remove unallowed characters from text.
        If *substitute* is defined, then replace
        the character with the given substitute.
    '''
    class D(dict):
        def __getitem__(self, key):
            return key if allowed(chr(key)) else substitute
    return text.translate(D())
```

This function is very flexible. It let's you easily specify rules for deciding which text is kept and which text is either replaced or removed.

Here's a simple example using the rule, "only allow characters that are in the unicode category L":

```
import unicodedata

def allowed(character):
    return unicodedata.category(character).startswith('L')

print(makesafe('the*ides&of*march', allowed, '_'))
print(makesafe('the*ides&of*march', allowed))
```

That code produces safe output as follows:

```
the_ides_of_march
theidesofmarch
```

Comment: Having substitute be a function of the non-allowed character would make this rather more flexible. Consider for example a perfectly valid finnish word hääyöaie, and how it would be molested to something like hyaie or h--y-aie with your current substitution mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

The following will remove accents from whatever characters Unicode can decompose into combining pairs, discard any weird characters it can't, and nuke whitespace:

```
# encoding: utf-8
from unicodedata import normalize
import re

original = u'ľ š č ť ž ý á í é'
decomposed = normalize("NFKD", original)
no_accent = ''.join(c for c in decomposed if ord(c)<0x7f)
no_spaces = re.sub(r'\s', '_', no_accent)

print no_spaces
# output: l_s_c_t_z_y_a_i_e
```

It doesn't try to get rid of characters disallowed on filesystems, but you can steal `DANGEROUS_CHARS_REGEX` from the file you linked for that.

Answer (score 2):

I'll throw my own (partial) solution here too:

```
import unicodedata

def deaccent(some_unicode_string):
    return u''.join(c for c in unicodedata.normalize('NFD', some_unicode_string)
               if unicodedata.category(c) != 'Mn')
```

This does not do all you want, but gives a few nice tricks wrapped up in a convenience method: `unicode.normalise('NFD', some_unicode_string)` does a decomposition of unicode characters, for example, it breaks 'ä' to two unicode codepoints `U+03B3` and `U+0308`.

The other method, `unicodedata.category(char)`, returns the enicode character category for that particular `char`. Category `Mn` contains all combining accents, thus `deaccent` removes all accents from the words.

But note, that this is just a partial solution, it gets rid of accents. You still need some sort of whitelist of characters you want to allow after this.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with

https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=slug

Its hard to come up with a scenario where one of these does not fit your needs.