# Downloading youtube mp3 - metadata encoding issue (python, youtube-dl, ffmpeg)

Tags: python, encoding, ffmpeg, metadata, youtube-dl

I'm trying to download audio from youtube with youtube-dl.exe and ffmpeg.exe (Windows 7), but I am having some troubles with encoding. I have to parse metadata manually, because when I try to use

```
--metadata-from-title "%(artist) - %(title)" --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DaU94Ld3fuM
```

I get ERROR: Could not interpret title of video as "%(artist) - %(title)"

Anyway, I wrote some code to save metadata with ffmpeg:

```
def download(url, title_first=False):
    if (0 == subprocess.call('youtube-dl --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 %s' % url)):
        #saves file in current directory in format: VID_TITLE-VID_ID.mp3
        video_id = url[url.find('=')+1:] #video id from URL (after ?v=)
        for f in os.listdir('.'):
            if video_id in f:
                filename = f
                break
        os.rename(filename, video_id+'.mp3') #name without non-ascii chars (for tests)
        video_title = filename[: filename.find(video_id)-1]

        output = video_title + '.mp3'
        title, artist = '', ''
        try: #parsing the title
            x = video_title.find('-')
            artist = video_title[:x].strip()
            title = video_title[x+1:].strip()
            if (title_first): output = '%s - %s.mp3' % (title, artist)
        except:
            pass

        x = 'ffmpeg -i "%s" -metadata title="%s" -metadata artist="%s" -acodec copy -id3v2_version 3 -write_id3v1 1 "%s"' \
                        % (video_id+'.mp3', title, artist, output)
        print x
        subprocess.call(x)
```

The file is downloaded and then cropped to given start and duration times (the code above is a simplified version). Filename is fine, but when I open the file with AIMP3, it shows rubbish instead of non-ascii characters:

[image]

I've tried to re-encode the final command with iso-8859-2, utf-8 and mbcs:

```
x = x.decode('cp1250').encode('iso-8859-2')
```

But non-ascii chars are still not readable. Passing an unicode command returns UnicodeEncodeError...

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing an `s` after each template field. Should be `--metadata-from-title "%(artist)s - %(title)s"`. You should also pass `--add-metadata` to write the metadata to file. So that final command will look like this:

`youtube-dl --metadata-from-title "%(artist)s - %(title)s" --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 --add-metadata https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DaU94Ld3fuM`

Comment: Thanks alot, that works perfectly! As far as I remember I was trying with "%(artist)s" and "%(title)s", but I never used --add-metadata. All non-ascii chars are present in the final tags.

Comment: I think this is not working for me? After running your command:
`[download] 100% of 6.69MiB in 00:10
[fromtitle] parsed artist: Aerosmith
[fromtitle] parsed title: Walk This Way (lyrics) [HD]
[ffmpeg] Adding metadata to 'Aerosmith - Walk This Way (lyrics) [HD]-xBg2LP223_8.m4a'
[ffmpeg] Destination: Aerosmith - Walk This Way (lyrics) [HD]-xBg2LP223_8.mp3
Deleting original file Aerosmith - Walk This Way (lyrics) [HD]-xBg2LP223_8.m4a (pass -k to keep)
[ffmpeg] Adding thumbnail to "Aerosmith - Walk This Way (lyrics) [HD]-xBg2LP223_8.mp3"
`
but then the mp3 file has no metadata in it?

Answer (score 0):

From this [SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9042515/normalizing-unicode-%5Ctext-to-filenames-etc-in-python) I think you are having this problem

```
import re
from unicodedata import normalize

_punct_re = re.compile(r'[\t !"#$%&\'()*\-/<=>?@\[\\\]^_`{|},.:]+')

def slugify(text, delim=u'-'):
    """Generates an slightly worse ASCII-only slug."""
    result = []
    for word in _punct_re.split(text.lower()):
        word = normalize('NFKD', word).encode('ascii', 'ignore')
        if word:
            result.append(word)
    return unicode(delim.join(result))
```

Usage:

```
>>> slugify(u'My International Text: åäö')
u'my-international-text-aao'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but filename itself is not a problem. The problem was encoding metadata inside the file, but dstftw has helped already.